# How do I add the additional type variables in my specification of an inductive type in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I defined an inductive type like this:

```
inductive I :: "tau ⇒ bool" where
rule0: "I C0" |
rule1: "I x" |
rule2: "Q x ⟹ I x" |
rule3: "Q x ⟹ I x'" |
rule4: "Q x ⟹ I (C1 x)" |
rule5: "Q (C1 x) ⟹ I x" |
rule6: "Q (C1 x) ⟹ I x'" |
rule7: "Q x ⟹ I (C2 x' x'')"
```

which I thought would be enough but Isabelle complains/warns me with:

```
Additional type variable(s) in specification of "I": 'a, 'b
```

I don't understand what this means. I know that it's saying that I should put somewhere that inductive predicate accepts any two type (as shown by the type variables `'a` and `'b`). But that isn't what I wanted to do. I just want the input to always be of type `tau` which is:

```
datatype tau = 
C0 |
C1 tau |
C2 tau tau
```

obviously these definitions are made up, not really meant to prove anything. I'm just curious to inspect the theorems (in particular induction) that it generates with these defintions.

**1) How do I have it stop complaining about my variables being arbitrary types and have them always be type `tau`?**

---

As an addition, I became really curious what the complaint means and how to fix it with the `'a` and `'b` syntax it is suggestion. Although that was not what I initially intended, I am curious to see a more general definition of my made up inductive predicate and see what iduct theorems it will generate.

**2) how do I define my inductive predicate with the arbitrary types Isabelle wants? where do I put `'a` and `'b` in the definition? If I don't what happens?**

Comment: The cause of this are rules 4 and 7. The left-hand side contains a variable `x` that does not appear on the right-hand side. Moreover, you haven't said what `Q` is. Is it a variable? Is it a parameter? What is its type? At the moment, Isabelle just thinks `Q` can be any predicate, so by rule 3 alone you can show that `I x` is true for all `x`. This is also where the extra type variables come from. Nothing in your definition constrains the type of `x` in rules 3 and 7, so Isabelle infers that these can have any type.

Comment: @ManuelEberl Isabelle inferred correctly that `Q` is any predicate. I assume it did that because it's on the LHS of a meta-implication, so that's one way of making sense of it (perhaps the only way). I am aware of the `for r where` idiom. I assume it's to fix a predicate somehow. Perhaps I can give it's type there. I've not played exhaustively with it so I'm not 100% what would happen. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ManuelEberl is the only way to constraint them by saying the type of `Q`? I want `Q` to he **any** predicate of type `tau => bool` (but not fixed).

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the type in my rules I can decorate the types in the inductive definition of `I`:

```
inductive I :: "tau ⇒ bool"  where
rule0: "I C0" |
rule1: "I x" |
rule2: "Q x ⟹ I x" |
rule3: "Q (x::tau) ⟹ I x'" |
rule4: "Q x ⟹ I (C1 x)" |
rule5: "Q (C1 x) ⟹ I x" |
rule6: "Q (C1 x) ⟹ I x'" |
rule7: "Q (x::tau) ⟹ I (C2 x' x'')"
```

now the theorems like this:

```
thm I.induct

⟦I ?x; ?P C0; ⋀x. ?P x; ⋀Q x. Q x ⟹ ?P x; ⋀Q x x'. Q x ⟹ ?P x'; ⋀Q x. Q x ⟹ ?P (C1 x); ⋀Q x. Q (C1 x) ⟹ ?P x; ⋀Q x x'. Q (C1 x) ⟹ ?P x'; ⋀Q x x' x''. Q x ⟹ ?P (C2 x' x'')⟧ ⟹ ?P ?x
```

Thanks Manuel Eberl!

Comment: The `Q` is still universally quantified in your introduction rules, which cannot be what you want. That makes your definition equivalent to `I x = True`. Then again, `rule1` alone already does that.

Comment: @ManuelEberl you are right, it's a silly example. That's ok, this isn't really a real proof. I just wanted to see the induction rule hypothesis myself for rules with constructors. A more realistic example would be to have the `for Q` construct to solve the issue you are referring to, which to my understanding fixes `Q` and assumes it's constant rather than quantifying universally for it.